# Same CSS but different results for Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a search element widget on the home page of my site. Inside the widget there are different tabs which represent search criteria. The issue is for those inner search tabs look different in Chrome and Safari.

I am attaching the screenshots for both the Chrome and Safari versions.

Chrome version (preferred version)
[image: The way tabs look in Chrome]

Safari version (would like to see it like it looks in Chrome)
[image: The way tabs look in Safari]

I tried playing around with it but all my hacks did was break it and make it worse. Can this be changed in Safari at all. There isnt much to the html, css code so I dont really know why it screws up in Safari.

Here is the public link for the site: 
http://kw-kw-sb-test-site.cs16.force.com/KWRI_Master_site

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to give us a link to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Does each one of the search criteria shift downward when selected?  The image that replaces the text of the criteria might be set to `vertical-align: bottom` or some other type of affect on the image.

Comment: It shifts down when selected in Safari not in Chrome. In Chrome it stays put and thats what I prefer.